# Setup a Google Tag Manager trigger which targets a specific entry of a Regular Expression table

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have successfully set up content grouping in GTM through a RegEx table, to get content grouping information in Google Analytics 4.

Now I need to set up a trigger, which works when a specific set of pages is visited.
I thought it's a good idea to target this behavior by adding a dedicated entry in that same content group RegEx table.

Now, I know how to set a trigger which target a RegEx table. But what I need here, is a trigger to target a specific entry of that table.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Of course, I could set another content group, but my container will get messy  if I need a dedicated RegEx table for each such case.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why need to target the entry: If you set up the RegEx table. The specific entry should be convert a result you set in the table. Can you just target the result? Or the result will be duplicated with others entry.